# find and display all indexes in a list based on keyword

Tags: list, indexing, python-3.4

I have the following code in Python 3 that finds and displays the first example of a searched for word in a list i.e. the word(s) 'now' is in position(s) 3, but if the word appears twice or more in the list, I can't find a way of displaying the second/third etc index. i.e. the word(s) 'now' appears in position(s) 3 and 5.

I've seen some very complicated versions online but want to see if I can keep it really simple. I know .index() only finds the first index, so is there another method I could use?

code:

```
sentence=input("Enter your sentence here: ")
sentence=sentence.lower()
words=(sentence.split())
print(words)
word_to_find=input("What word position do you want to find? ")
word_to_find=word_to_find.lower()

if word_to_find in words:
    position=words.index(word_to_find)
    print( "The word ", word_to_find, "is in position(s): ",position+1)
else:
    print("No word exists")
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

try;

`positions = [ind for ind, x in enumerate(words) if x == word_to_find]`

Now `positions` will be a list of all index of `word_to_find` in `words`.

Comment: This is great. Many thanks Praveen.I will research into what this line actually means.